# Combining two surfaces

Tags: directx, directx9

I have two surfaces. One is the back-buffer, the other is a surface with some user-interface overlay graphics already rendered onto it. Both surfaces have identical properties (size, format...etc).

I want to copy one surface onto the other and create the UI overlay.

Is this possible to do?